# The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed, error login

Tags: entity-framework, sqlexception

I have Windows 7, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010.

First question: I don't change my password in sql, although my security its setting follow:

- server authentication: sql server windows authentication mode
- login auditing: Failed logins only

and for user sa or any users:

```
permission: Grant
Login: Enabled
```

but, my any password will 32 numbers.

Second question:

Then, I never can connect to database in Visual Studio, such as Entity Framework way, with uid and with `Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;`

So, when I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> in VS, and I expect true working my app and ajax, I instead get error.

My code:

```
function FillGrid() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_process.aspx?cmd=FillGrid",
        type: "POST",
        data: null,
        async: true,
        success: function (dataFromServer) {
            d = eval("(" + dataFromServer + ")");
            alert(d[0].email);
        },
        error: function (XMLResponse) {
            alert(XMLResponse.responseText);
        }

    });
}
```

My error is alert:

> The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.

and:

> SqlException (0x80131904): The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6352224

Answer (score 2):

User Instances are a Sql Server **Express** only feature.

Comment: Do i need to reinstall sqlserver or install express version, please get me link for download and install.

Comment: You can install an Express Instance in parallel no need to uninstall the existing database. What Express Version 2005, 2008, 2012 doesn't matter at the moment. Just be aware that user instances are a deprecated feature and might be gone in a future sql server incarnation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do fix this in VS 2010:

In VS2010 IDE, right-click on your database > `Modify Connection` > `Advanced` > `Source`.

In source change `User Instance` to `false` then in Sql Explorer panel refresh to see your database contents - that's all that's needed.

---

Note: some times you need to delete `User Instance = true;` in your connection string (that for example you use in your data access class).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new ADO.net entity data model
2. In the wizard: select 'EF designer from database'
3. Select new connection button
4. Change data source from 'microsoft sql server' to 'microsoft sql server database file'
5. Browse your database.